# Isn't it possible for Muslim Ummah to unite under one identity?

Tags: shia-sunni, sects

We can clearly see that until Muslims were just Muslims and not "Shia" and "Sunni" they ruled the world (well most of it). These major categories subdivided into countless sub-categories and today you can hardly see someone who is a Muslim and that's it. Consequently, others took over leaving us disgraced.

Now that educational revolution is at its finest and we are so called intellectuals, why can't we, as the new generation, try to patch up the gaps? Why can't we respect other Muslims merely on the basis of the Kalima we share and leave the rest to be judged by Allah Ta'aala at the Promised Day. Can't we leave the controversial topics aside and be brothers as muhajireen and ansaar?

Even here at Stackexchange, people get into controversial debates developing even more hatred in their heart for their Muslim brothers.

My question is: Are we too far from uniting under one flag of Islam and what is the thing that stops us from doing so?

Comment: AFAIK we are *less than* far from uniting and media (songs and movies) are stopping us to think correctly.

Comment: I agree with you. The worldly desires keep us so occupied that we never give a thought to these matters.

Comment: Great responses and what I conclude is although it is destined to go like this since the Prophet(SAW) informed us about it but as an individual, all of us should respect the very Kalima we share with our Muslim brothers. Whatever differs should be kept out untouched.

Comment: *what is the thing that stops us from doing so?* **ego, lack of mutual agreement, and *shaitan*.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

salaam brother

I agree with you 100%, but unfortunately this cannot be the case, as time goes on. The prophet PBUH himself predicted this in a hadith, where he said

> My ummah will be divided into seventy three sects. All of them will be in the Fire except one.

from this we can conclude that no matter how hard we try, it won't work because there will always be contradicting views. Despite this, I honestly do wish we can all be united, as this is what will strengthen the muslims once again.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to politics. Religion has nothing to do with it. Throughout the Islamic ages, Shia/Sunnis controlled the Caliphates with positives and negatives on both ends.

It will be impossible to have unity regardless, since there will always be difference of opinions. There can be a control, but not shared. I think of American Republicans/Democrats when I think so, both love their country but have different ways of implementing such love and barely agree on their differences.

The only person to have such blessings from Allah was prophet Mohamed, as stated in the Quran:

> لو أنفقت ما في الأرض جميعا ما ألفت بين قلوبهم ولكن الله ألف بينهم
>
> If you spend every wealth on earth to have them unite under one heart you won't be able to, but we have done so. [8:63]

Comment: I agree with you  that (probably) it will be impossible to have unity, but I assume we do our best in order to reaching unity as much as possible as the Muslims who are interested in the unity as definitely the Prophet (s) are interested in the unity between his Ummah in order to making a stronger Islam. Tawakalto-alAllah. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No there wont be uniting under one flag (unless God decides otherwise), but everyone is united to different degrees through God, their faith, and Islam as a religion. I have faith that the average Sunni man is the same good and honest person as the average Shia man, Whabbi man, Christian man, Aethist man, or whatever label exists. Isn't that better than everyone saluting a flag?

---

I agree with @AmericanMuslim. Its politics and everyone will always disagree, but disagreement is healthy until someone decides to force their point of view instead of listening. It'd be nice to make this a comment instead of an answer...

Comment: Personally, what I learnt from history, disagreement tend to lead fighting.

Comment: I think the disagreements are used as an excuse for the fighting to happen and lack of religious disagreement would not stop anything. Thats politics.